are history of cryptography questions allowed?
I want to make some questions regarding the history of cryptography. particularly I want material/information  about WWII german code breakers.
Is this the site to ask the question or should I ask in other SE site?
the concrete question I want to ask is the following, but reading the comments I imagine it belongs into history.se more than here.
There is a lot of material about british code breakers but not about german team. Did the german army (or they allies) had a team that is equivalent to the one at bletchey park in England?

Probably depends on the exact form of the question. It should be relatively specific, and the answers shouldn't just consist of links.

Are they more about historical cryptographic techniques, or historical facts pertaining to cryptography? Eg, "how was Enigma broken?" vs "who broke Enigma"?
